# Select nth row using where condition in oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table having business days stored into it. I want to get 5th business day based on the input date i give.  For an example please consider below table

```
    BUSINESS DAY
8/06/2004 12:00:00 AM
8/07/2004 12:00:00 AM
8/08/2004 12:00:00 AM
8/09/2004 12:00:00 AM
8/10/2004 12:00:00 AM
8/13/2004 12:00:00 AM
8/14/2004 12:00:00 AM
8/15/2004 12:00:00 AM
8/16/2004 12:00:00 AM
```

Here my input date is 8/08/2004 12:00:00 AM my output should be 8/15/2004 12:00:00 AM. Please help to construct query for this.  Please note that based on the requirement i may need past dates as well.

Note: I want to fetch the record neither from top nor bottom. I have to fetch the 5th record only from the row where my input condition is satisfied

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to fetch the rows neither from top nor bottom of the table. But only after condition is satisfied @EvilTeach .